# How to pass enum as a parameter in a optional method within a protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
enum SearchBarAction {
  case Cancel
  case Bookmark
  case Location
  case Category
  case Filter
}

@objc protocol SearchBarNavigatorDelegate: class {
  optional func searchBarNavigator(clicked: SearchBarAction)
}
```

This gave me an error

```
Method cannot be a member of an @objc protocol because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C
```

I need this method to be optional therefore i cannot remove @objc to solve this.

Is there any way to use optional protocol method while passing an enum as a parameter to the method?

Comment: You could pass enums rawValue (e.g. String) and convert back to enum.

Comment: @Darko that method works but i would prefer if i can just pass the enum because i would like the method not to accept any unexpected string

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It will work if you declare the enumeration as `@objc` with raw type:

```
@objc enum SearchBarAction: Int {
    case cancel
    case bookmark
    case location
    case category
    case filter
}
```

Comment: Cool. Didn't know this.

Comment: @Rob Thanks! Exactly what i need